# How do I take each line of a text file and insert them into a web form? Specifically, for testing domain name availability

Tags: ruby, forms, scripting, web-scraping, insertion

I wrote a Ruby script that appended "data" to the beginning of every word of the English dictionary, and then filtered out various strings using different parameters, and now I want to use a site like namecheap or gandi.net in order to take each of these strings and insert them into the domain name availability checker in order to determine which ones are available.

It is my understanding that this will involve making a POST HTTP request of some kind, as well as grabbing the element in question, but I don't really understand the dynamics of what to read about in order to do this kind of thing.

I imagine that after a few requests I will be limited, but as a learning exercise I am still curious as to how I would go about doing this.

I inspected the element (on namecheap) to see what the tag looked like, to find any uniquely identifiable class/id names that I could use to grab that specific part of the source, and found that inside a fieldset tag, there was a line of HTML that I can't seem to paste here, so here is a picture:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any guidance in helping me learn about web scripting!

Comment: I don't know Ruby, so I can't help you with the code, but I have some general tips. If you want to avoid being blocked by the server, you should try to look as much as a human as possible. This involves setting headers correctly (user-agent, referer), possibly setting some cookies (you would need to inspect the webpage to see what you need), be nice to the server by reducing the number of requests/minute, etc. etc.

Comment: The first thing to do nowadays when you want to do some scraping is to check whether there's an API available. Gandi seems to have one [here](http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/domain/usage.html).